# LineageOS/OpenGApps refuse to install on SM-G901F

Tags: rooting, samsung-galaxy-s-5, lineageos

Very annoying.

I'm trying to install LineageOS on Samsung Galaxy S5 Plus (SM-G901F), which used to run with stock OS before.

- I successfully installed TWRP
- I backed up my partitions and wiped them
- Downloaded Lineageos (lineage-16.0-20200416-nightly-kccat6-signed)
- Downloaded Addonsu (addonsu-16.0-arm-signed)
- Downloaded OpenGApps
- Installation of all packages in one run seems to finish without problems.
- When I start the system it takes half an hour to boot but eventually resets and boots into recovery. I never get to see more than the moving bubbles.

I tried the following OpenGApps-packages:

- open_gapps-arm-9.0-aroma-20200418 (wouldn't even install)
- open_gapps-arm-9.0-super-20200418
- open_gapps-arm-9.0-stock-20200418

outcome is the same for all. I also tried without addonsu, but outcome was the same. Now, what are the next steps? Or what did I miss?

- Is the storage of my phone too small?
- Did I select wrong OS version?
- does the opengapps version not match that of the OS?
- Should I try without opengapps?

**Update**

Using nightly build 20200423 with opengapps-nano worked. But not with addonsu. Can I install addonsu later? Or does it suffer the same problem as opengapps that it can't be installed in a second run?

Comment: Just to make sure, are you following [the official guide](https://wiki.lineageos.org/devices/kccat6/install) and tried 'nano' for OpenGApps instead?

Comment: Yes, followed official guide, tried also nano now. Same result.

Comment: If something does not work fall back to the bare minimum (LineageOS without su and GApps). You are using a nightly version - those versions can work but does not have to. Try a newer or older version (several days). Make sure you also wipe the data partition.

Comment: Ha! Installing the latest lineageos-version w/o additional stuff worked. I'm going to inch  forward. Thanks so far, I'm doing more tests and update either my question or report success.

Comment: Update: Installing with lineageos and opengapps w/o addonsu worked. I'll add that to the question.